# In VMware what are the differences between the network connection options?

Tags: networking, vpn, vmware, tcpip

In VMware there are the network options
 [image: screen shot of VMware network options]

I'm unsure what to choose. I've red the [documentation here](https://www.vmware.com/support/ws55/doc/ws_net.html) but find the situations it describes are too complex with my needs. I just want the internet to be fast and reliable. The host computer connects to the internet through a VPN. Which option should be chosen? If someone could provide me with the pros and cons for each that would be appreciated. For example, if one has the least overhead I should probably just use it.

Answer (score 2):

The quick and dirty run down of the different options are as follows :

#### Bridged :

This will put your Virtual Machine on the same LAN as the HOST. It will have its own IP Address (you can configure static or get it from the DHCP server on your LAN). Since your virtual machine has its own IP Address it will have full access to your LAN. That means that other PCs on your LAN can connect directly to it using its IP Address.

#### NAT :

This setting takes your HOST IP Address and shares it with your Virtual Machine. So your Virtual will be on its own Network that is separate from your LAN and any requests it makes will be NATTED before it is sent out.

That means that any requests your Virtual makes for outside resources (i.e. your LAN or the internet) will be changed (NATTED) by your host in the same way that your ISP router changes the packets as they leave your LAN from your unique machine LAN IP Address to the ISP provided Public IP Address.

So if you wanted another computer (either inside your own LAN or from the internet) to directly connect to your virtual it would first have to go through your HOST IP. So you would have to setup some Port Forwarding rules that would allow the traffic from outside to go directly into your Virtual (again similar to how you setup on your ISP router).

#### Host-only :

This will put your Virtual on a different network then your LAN. You will have no access to your LAN or the internet. You will only have access to the HOST itself but not beyond (unless you setup what the VM Ware documentation calls 'proper routing or proxy software' to connect this new network to your LAN network).

This is useful if you need a machine that is completely isolated from anything outside of your HOST.

#### Custom :

This will create a new network that you can choose if it should be connected to HOST or not. I do believe that you should be able to connect this new virtual network to your LAN through some auto-bridge setting (I don't have it in front of me now).

#### LAN Segment :

This is where you can create multiple private networks and you can configure them separately to your liking. These are good for making your own virtual 'labs' where you can configure different VLANS. There are many possibilities.

In addition to reading the VM Documentation see [THIS ARTICLE](http://www.virtualizationadmin.com/articles-tutorials/vmware-server-workstation-player-articles/understanding-virtual-networking-vmware-workstation-9.html).

I am not really sure what your specific need is but I hope this gives you a better idea of what the different options mean.

If you just want to setup a virtual machine and have it be apart of your LAN then choose `BRIDGED` mode. This will give your Virtual its own IP Address and it shouldn't feel any different then if you setup a new physical box on your LAN (aside from the nice chunk of memory its using up on your host, that is).